# python - storing lists as text and converting back again without separation issues

Tags: python

what I want is to read and write list of texts to a txt file without separation issues

---

**here's a example from browsers**

- if I search 'cats dogs', the link becomes 'cats+dogs'
- if I search 'cats+dogs', the link becomes 'cats%2Bdogs'
- if I search 'cats%2Bdogs', the link becomes 'cats%252Bdogs'

---

it is little ahead of my skills rn (:

```
lis = ['abc', 'def', '123']
def list_to_text(lis):
    pass

def text_to_list(text):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to serialize the list into a string, store it, then deserialize that string. You likely want to use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module, as your example only uses primitives in your list. Like this:

```
import json

lis = ['abc', 'def', '123']
serialized = json.dumps(lis)
# store `serialized` somewhere, or to a file with json.dump()

out = json.loads(serialized)  # or use json.load() if reading from a file
print(out)
```

If you need to store data that JSON does not support, try using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) instead (though, note that you should only pickle trusted data, not user input). It has the same interface as the `json` module. Like this:

```
import pickle

lis = ['abc', 'def', '123']
serialized = pickle.dumps(lis)
# store `serialized` somewhere, or to a file with json.dump()

out = pickle.loads(serialized)  # or use json.load() if reading from a file
print(out)
```